# jquery comment system on.(...click) issue

Tags: php, jquery, selector, comments

I'm having trouble keeping event handlers attached to future loaded selectors. For example, when pull.php is loaded, the confirmdelete is no longer hidden, and also the click event handlers no longer exist. I am new to jquery and ajax. Below is my code. 
    $id= (int)strip_tags($_GET['id']);

```
$(document).ready(function() { //make a comment delete js file eventually, just so we can reference the source
    $('.confirmdeletecomment').hide();
    $('.deletecomment').on("click", function(e){
        var cid = $(this).attr("id");
        $('a#c'+cid).show(500, function(){ //right now as call back
            $(this).on("click", function(e){
            var id = $(this).attr("id"); 
            var did = id.substring(1);  
            $.post(

                'deletecommentdata.php?cid='+did,

                function(data)
                {
                   $("#commentarea").load("pull.php?id=<? echo $id; ?>");
                   $("#comment").val("");
                   $('.confirmdeletecomment').hide();

                }

                )

                e.preventDefault();//so it doesn't interpret is as an anchor link

                });



                });

    e.preventDefault();//so it doesn't interpret is as an anchor link
    });


});

</script>
```

the below script is the php part:

```
<div id="commentarea">

<?

$query = mysql_query("SELECT users.user_id, users.username, users.miniavatar, comments.comment_id, comments.comment, comments.time_stamp FROM users INNER JOIN comments ON users.user_id=comments.products_users_user_id WHERE comments.products_products_id = '$id' ORDER BY comments.time_stamp DESC");

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

?>
<div id='singlecomment'>

<hr class="comment" />
<table>
<col width="*" />
<col width="400" />
<col width="*" />    
<tr>
<td valign = "top" rowspan="2">
<a href="collection.php?profile=<? echo $row2['user_id']; ?>"><img src="<? echo $row2['miniavatar']; ?>" height="52" width="52" /></a> <br />
<?  
if ($user_id == $row2['user_id']) { 
    $cid = $row2['comment_id'];


    echo "<a id='$cid' class='deletecomment' title='Delete Post'>X</a> &nbsp";
    echo "<a id='c$cid' class='confirmdeletecomment'>confirm</a>";
}   
?>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<a class="blue" href="collection.php?profile=<? echo $row2['user_id']; ?>"> <? echo $row2['username']; ?> </a>
</td>
<td> 
<span class="date"><? echo date("F j, Y g:i a ", strtotime($row2['time_stamp'])); ?> </span>
</td>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<? echo stripslashes($row2['comment']); ?> <br/><br/>
</td>
</tr>
</table> 
</div>
```

Comment: .live() seems to work, but stll can't keep confirm hidden. also know that live is deprecated...

Comment: .on() also attaches the handler to each element or future elements, just like live used to do it, but without the complication live() brought.

Comment: technically, `on` method, when used with event delegation, don't attach handler to all current and futures elements, but only on a parent element

Comment: Anonymous, could you indent correctly your code please ? I can't read it :(

Comment: any idea why confirmdelete is not staying hidden after the pull.php is loaded?

Comment: If I may could read the code correctly I could search where is the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is use 'on' like it's meant. Right there all you're doing is binding a .click event to that element in the selector.

What you want is:

`$('body').on("click", ".deletecomment", function(e){`

or something in place of 'body' that is a wrapper that can watch that level of the DOM for new elements to apply the event too.

Comment: alright that makes sense. thanks for the response. how would i keep the confirmdelete hidden though after the load of pull.php. pull.php loads elements with this same class.

Comment: it looks like it's already in your callback, you may have to mess with hierarchy, and order of operations to get it just right, but I don't have all your code so I can't really see what it's doing, and I'm a visual person.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing the event got messed up since you are the passing the event handler from

```
$('.deletecomment').on("click", function(e){
```

to

```
 $(this).on("click", function(e){
```

Change the event names, if you really want to handle them separately. More like updating your second handler as these will do goo

```
$(this).on("click", function(event){
```

---

Since I dont have your markup structure, I am guessing, when you are loading `pull.php` to `#commentarea`, another element with class `confirmdelete` should have been loaded as well, thus making the code execution incomplete logically.

Put, `$(".confirmdelete").hide();` right above `e.preventDefault()` to see if I am right.

Comment: thanks for the reply. also why is my confirmdelete not staying hidden after pull.php loads?

Comment: yep another element with class confirmdelete should have been loaded as well. i put `$(".confirmdelete").hide();` right above `e.preventDefault()` and now the confirm stays hidden no matter what. wont respond to click of `$(".deletecomment")

Comment: @Anonymous, So you want .confirmdelete to show up once the deletecomment is clicked......

Comment: yep and then when pull reloads the comments i want .confirmdelete to be hidden again for all the comments.

Comment: @Anonymous, Ok Update your question with the markup, I will create a simpel demo for you :)

Comment: kk i've added more code. hopefully its enough for u to create a demo. if not let me know. thanks :) alot

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8504/discussion-between-starx-and-anonymous)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the event delegation system http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score -1):

Try JQuery live. [more info](http://api.jquery.com/live/) It should be something like the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() { //make a comment delete js file eventually, just so we can reference the source
    $('.confirmdeletecomment').hide();
    $('.deletecomment').live("click", function(){
        var cid = $(this).attr("id");
        $('a#c'+cid).show(500, function(){ //right now as call back
            $(this).on("click", "a", function(e){
            var id = $(this).attr("id"); 
            var did = id.substring(1);  
            $.post(

        'deletecommentdata.php?cid='+did,

        function(data)
        {
            $("#commentarea").load("pull.php?id=<? echo $id; ?>");
            $("#comment").val("");
            $('.confirmdeletecomment').hide();

        }

        )

            e.preventDefault();//so it doesn't interpret is as an anchor link

            });



        });

        e.preventDefault();//so it doesn't interpret is as an anchor link
        });


});

</script>
```

Comment: `jQuery.fn.live` usage is deprecated in jQuery 1.7+

Comment: Thanks, I was using 1.6, did n't knew about deprecation

Comment: No problem :) also, `jQuery.fn.live` sometimes behave weirdly, that's one reason why `jQuery.fn.delegate` was created in the first place :)